# Terminate long-running process _and_ receive stdout in Java

Tags: java, process, timeout, interrupt

I'm trying to run a native executable from Java using the [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) API. The native code performs a long-running computation, which might have to be interrupted after a time-out.

Ideally, I'd like to receive the standard output using `getInputStream()` avoiding an intermediate file.

Here is the conundrum:

1. It is not possible to *first* wait for the process termination and *then* starting to read stdout. In that case, `waitFor` waits indefinitely.
2. If I *first* start reading stdout and *then* check the exit code, the code stops responding to `Thread.interrupt()`. To see the issue, see the following “minimal” example:

Bash code in `computation.sh` that simulates a long-running (5 seconds) computation:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    END=$((`date +%s` + 5))
    while [ `date +%s` -lt $END ]; do
        echo "Heavy computation" > /dev/null
    done

    echo "Answer is 42"
```

Java code in `Test.java` that runs the Bash code in a separate thread and interrupts it after 1 second:

```
    import java.io.*;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            Thread waitForProcess = new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Process unixProcess = null;
                    try {
                        unixProcess = new ProcessBuilder("./computation.sh").start();

                        try (BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(unixProcess.getInputStream()))) {

                            String line;
                            // Exactly here, Java stops
                            // responding to Thread.interrupt():
                            while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
                                System.out.println(line);
                            }
                        }

                        int retval = unixProcess.waitFor();
                        System.out.println("Retval: " + retval);

                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Computation interrupted.");

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println("IOException: " + ex);

                    } finally {
                        if (unixProcess != null) {
                            unixProcess.destroy();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            waitForProcess.start();
            // Timeout of 1000 ms
            waitForProcess.join(1000L);
            waitForProcess.interrupt();
            // Additional grace time
            waitForProcess.join(100L);

            // Timeout has occured
            if (waitForProcess.isAlive()) {
                System.out.println("Timeout occurred");
            }
        }
    }
```

Ideally, the Java code should print `Timeout occurred` and exit after 1 second. In fact, it waits all 5 seconds and eventually prints `Answer is 42`.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need two threads: one to read the input, and the other to handle timeout.

Comment: I know what you mean, but this does not seem to help. If I create 2 additional threads, #1 for timeout and #2 for reading stdout, thread #2 does not receive the relevant exception.

Comment: You don't need to interrupt the second thread: once the process is terminated, the stream will get closed, and it'll get notified that way.